# Regex in bash script not matching number pattern

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script which works out who should be doing the cooking in a team of 4. The script takes the week of the year and divides it by 4. If there is **no decimal value**, it is Sandra's turn. If it contains **.25**, it is Christina's turn. If it contains **.5**, it is Zack's turn. If it contains **.75**, it is Peter's turn.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to check whose turn it is to cook

let week=$(date +%W)
echo "Current week of the year is $week"

let teamsize=4
counter=`echo "$week/$teamsize"|bc -l`
echo "Current week's counter is $counter"

if [[ "$counter" = ^[0-9]*\.0*$ ]]
    then echo "Sandra's turn"
elif [[ "$counter" = ^[0-9]*\.250*$ ]]
    then echo "Christina's turn"
elif [[ "$counter" = ^[0-9]*\.50*$ ]]
    then echo "Zack's turn"
elif [[ "$counter" = ^[0-9]*\.750*$ ]]
    then echo "Peter's turn"
else echo "No cook matched!"
fi
```

For the current week, it is not matching any of the entries. The week of the year is **18** and this is the output:

```
Current week of the year is 18
Current week's counter is 4.50000000000000000000
No cook matched!
```

Appreciate any help figuring out how to match the variable counter to the regex number pattern. Thanks.

Comment: Use `=~` instead of `=`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421460/bash-regex-and-https-regex101-com

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Thanks all. I got solution from Matias below. But I will go through all the resources above as they will probably help me solve the specific problem with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shorter version of your script using awk.

```
awk  -v date=$(date +%W) -v teamsize=4 '
BEGIN{ 
    turn= sprintf("%.2f",date / teamsize);
    if( turn ~ /^[0-9]*\.0*$/ ) { print "Sandra'"'"'s turn" }
    else if( turn ~ /^[0-9]*\.250*$/ ) { print "Christina'"'"'s turn" }
    else if( turn ~ /^[0-9]*\.50*$/ ) { print "Zack'"'"'s turn" }
    else if( turn ~ /^[0-9]*\.750*$/ ) { print "Peter'"'"'s turn" }
    else { print "No cook matched!" }
}'
```

Hope its useful for you.